# Make second UITextField firstresponder after the first UITextField did finish editing and press Done

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextfield, xcode4.5

I have created two UITextFields dynamically, when tapped on a certain CA Layer. I have made the first textfield the first responder, what I want is, when I enter text in first Textfield and press done, I want the second textfield to be the first responder.
n thats what I did for this in textFieldShouldReturn.

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (titleField.returnKeyType== UIReturnKeyDone) {

        NSString *title = [textField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        if (title.length>0 )
        {
            [self changeLayersTitle:title];
        }

        [dateField becomeFirstResponder];

    if (dateField.returnKeyType==UIReturnKeyDone)
    {
        NSString *date = [dateField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        if (date.length>0)
        {
            [self changeLayersDate:date];
        }
    }

        [dateField resignFirstResponder];
        [bgLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
        [titleField removeFromSuperview];
        [dateField removeFromSuperview];


    }
    return NO;
}
```

Now, when I enter press Done after entring text in first one, it dismissed both of the textfields, bt shows me the keyboard.
So, what am I missing or did wrong or do I have to put it somewhere else. please help me out.

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean by the last part of the question !

Comment: When I tap on a layer, it creates two textfields. first textfield is set as a first responder, and when I enter text in the first textfield and press done, it removes both of the textfield from the view n only shows me the keyboard, instead I want to remove the textfields after entering text in both of the fields, but its hapening right after I press done after entering text in the first field and not allowing me to enter text in the second field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you were comparing the `returnKeyType` property of the text fields. You should compare the text fields for equality, and if the return key was pressed on the first text field, then make the second text field the new responder.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == titleField) {
        [dateField becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else if (textField == dateField) {
        // Return button pressed on 2nd field. Do something
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I did so, but still the result is same.
tell me what else , i did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In your done button callback method, can't you just set your second text field as the first responder?

You don't need to resignFirstResponder on your first text field.